# How to use draw:deletestart in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to perform some operation when user clicks on delete button in leaflet.
This is how I am doing :

```
map.on('draw:deletestart', function(e) {
    alert("started");
});
```

But it is not triggering when I click the delete button. 
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this in internet explorer. I ran the same code in mozilla firefox and chrome and it's working fine.